# Is plugin needed for php code completion in Geany?

Tags: 12.04, php, auto-completion, geany

I'm new to Geany IDE. I have installed basic Geany without any plugins from ubuntu software center. I couldn't find code completion for php when I press Ctrl space. Is plugin needed for this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to install the `geany-plugins` package :

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugins
```